# Getting input element name out of $_POST array when element name is unknown

Tags: php, string, parsing, post

I have a PHP file that includes another file which is used to create a table by looping through the result of a MySQL query and then returning all the HTML and PHP variables as a string. That string is echoed in a div tag.

The PHP function that creates the table also creates input elements with unique names and IDs from the names of the Row/Column it is in. This means every control is unique and I do not know which will be used to submit the data. This was done so I could use in-line editing via JavaScript. This way, the user only has to click the element in the table on the page, and the hidden input controls are shown.

Upon clicking submit the form posts. To know where the data should go in the database and how to generate the SQL string for the update, I need to grab the text box's name that was posted. The post array will only contain the two elements, the submit button and the text box. How do I parse this name?

currently I am checking to see if the submit button has been set with the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
  //do stuff here
  $sql= update TABLENAME set ...

  $results = $dbConnect->prepare($sql);
}
```

etc.

sample `$_POST` array content is this:

```
Array ( [submit] => submit [newText_primaryKey_columnName] => User Input Text )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know there will be exactly two keys in the array and you only want the key of the one that is not submit, remove submit from the array, what's left is your key:

```
$post = $_POST;
unset($post['submit']);
$keys = array_keys($post);
$key = $keys[0];
```

A full example:

```
<?php
//$post = $_POST;
$post = array('submit' => True, 'some key I made up' => 'foobar');
unset($post['submit']);
$keys = array_keys($post);
$key = $keys[0];

print $key;
// some key I made up
```

Comment: wont that give the content inside of the element and not the element name itself?

Comment: You can also use `<input name="fields[myfieldname]">` which turn into an array in php like `$_POST['fields']['myfieldname']`. This will allow you to loop over it `foreach ( $_POST['fields'] as $key => $value)` to get the keys and values of multiple fields.

Comment: No, `array_keys` returns all the keys of the array. So `$key` is your key, `$_POST[$key]` is your value.

Comment: I just tried it I got notice and an error
                                                                        notice:  Undefined offset: 0   error: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: Sounds like you're passing in something other than your $_POST array.

Comment: I added a full example. Are you actually posting data? If not $_POST will be empty.

Comment: I just tried to run your modified code... it now prints the word Array

Comment: Try the full example, I actually ran that code through PHP. If it's not working as advertised there's a transcription error or something else awry with other code in your script. This discussion is moving beyond what stackoverflow is meant for.

Comment: It might help to post the actual code snippet you're having issue with.

Answer (score 0):

If you start all your Cell Id's off with a standard name such as cell, its then very easy to pull it out.

```
//Assuming CellID's Like cell_1, cell_2, cell_3 etc

foreach ($_POST as $Key => $Value)  //Check all posted values
{
    if (strpos('cell',$Key) !== false ) //if cell is at the begining of the key name
    {
        $OurKey = $Key; 
            //This will put cell into $temp and our id will be put in $CellID
        list($temp,$CellID) = implode('_', $OurKey);
        break;
    }

}

//Do Something With Our ID
SubmitData($CellID, $Value);
```

I hope this is what you are after.

One a sort of related note, you might find javascript libraries such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) or [jquery](http://jquery.org) useful in reducing the number of embedded forms you need.  Worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

If your `$_POST` array looks like this:

```
Array ( [submit] => submit [newText_primaryKey_columnName] => User Input Text )
```

Then you can find the key that is not the submit input:

```
$my_key = '';
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        if ($key != 'submit') {
            $my_key = $key;
        }
    }
}

//you can now access the value of your text input using $_POST[$my_key]
//you can also determine what to do with your information

$tmp = explode("_", $my_key);//$tmp[0] = "newText"; $tmp[1] = "primaryKey"; $tmp[2] = "columnName";
```